# How to pass multiple arguments in Multiprocessing executor.map() function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arguments

I have been watching several videos on Multiprocessing `map` function.

I know that I can send one list as an argument to the function I want to target with Multiprocessing, and that will call the same function n times (dependent upon the size of that passed list).

What I am struggling to do is what if I want to pass multiple arguments to that function?

I basically have a List whose size is `n` (it can vary but for current case, its 209)

My function requires 3 arguments...

1. the index of the list (0, 1, 2 etc.)
2. Another list containing data
3. A fixed integer value

I could have used the 2nd and 3rd arguments as global variables, but that doesn't work for me because I have to call the map function in a while loop... and in every another iteration, the values of these two will change.

My function *returns two values* which I need to access in the function from where it was called. This is what I have tried but it didn't work for me,

```
def main_fun():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 

        results = executor.map(MyFun, (row, pop[0].data, fitness) for row in range(0, len(pop[0].data)))

        for result in results:
            print(result)
```

I also tried to use `ZIP` function but again, with no success.

Comment: Use a tuple to pack arguments into one argument. The target function can then unpack it.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for mp, you'll see its full of examples that do just what @MichaelButscher describes.  Create a helper function that takes a single tuple as an argument and is the target of the executor.map.  That helper function then calls `MyFun`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher but how can I append a complete list of indexes in that... That is, I want the map function to make as many processes according to size of my data list.... So how can I do this? Make a list of tuples? Every index of that list will contain one tuple which will also consist one index value? And then pass that complete list as argument? I tried to do this, but it gave me an error.

Comment: A list (or other sequence) of tuples is exactly the idea. Show the full traceback of the error message in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your second and third arguments to your worker function (i.e. the first argument to `map`), then you can use method `functools.partial` to have the second and third arguments specified without resorting to the use of global variables. If your worker functions is, for example, `foo`, then:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def foo(idx: int, lst: list, int_value: int):
    ...

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        worker = partial(foo, lst=pop[0].data, int_value=fitness)
        executor.map(worker, range(0, len(pop[0].data)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**So now we only have to pass to `map` function `worker`, which will be called two fixed arguments, and a single *iterable* argument.**

If you are executing the `map` call in a loop, you will, of course, create a new `worker` functions by passing to `functools.partial` new arguments.

For example:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def foo(idx: int, lst: list, int_value: int):
    print(idx, lst[idx] * int_value, flush=True)

def main():
    l = [3, 5, 7]
    fitness = 9
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        worker = partial(foo, lst=l, int_value=fitness)
        executor.map(worker, range(0, len(l)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
0 27
1 45
2 63
```